# Unique constraint on a complexType instead of an element

Tags: xsd

I have the following XSD structure:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:ns="http://abc/">
  ...
  <xs:element name="abc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="map"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ...
  <xs:element name="map">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry" type="ns:MapEntryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="entry">
      <xs:selector xpath="entry"/>
      <xs:field xpath="key"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="MapEntryType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:anyType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is doing its job.

The `map` element now has to be called something different based on whichever is the wrapper, so the name is sometimes `map`, sometimes `properties`, sometimes `options`, etc.

Therefore I want to genericize the `map` element.

I tried doing the following:

- Making `map` a `xs:complexType` and changing `ref` to `type`.

  - This resulted in `xs:unique` not being accepted and failed
- Making `map` a `xs:complexType`, changing `ref` to `type` and moving the `xs:unique` constraint to the element definitions.

  - This worked but resulted in the XSD having a lot of `xs:unique` present in the document.

Isn't there a way to simply tell that I want a specific structure and it containing unique elements without having to repeat the unique constraint everywhere?

Comment: As you cannot use XSD 1.1 another solution is wrap your `<entry>` list in a element named `<entries>` so you only define `<xs:unique>` once. Not sure if this the solution you have choosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, it is not possible. Both XSD 1.0 and 1.1 place the identity constraints under an element; a constraint cannot be globally defined, therefore there is no "reuse" per se, other than that of the enclosing element. Given your scenario (different element names for different needs) it is not possible to reuse.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've gone to the redefinition of every possible name so far and I'm using references just like before. This seems the less boilerplate option.

Comment: Actually in XSD 1.1 you can define once a complete `xs:unique` (with name, selector and fields) inside an element and then in other elements elsewhere you can use `xs:unique ref="name"` without defining the selector and fields again.

Comment: Good to know! Unfortunately, I use XSD 1.0. I'll comment the document to keep this information available when we update to XSD 1.1.

Answer (score 4):

As [Petru Gardea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886533/petru-gardea) said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32832922/3870761)

> Both XSD 1.0 and 1.1 place the identity constraints under an element

So you have to add xs:unique to every element, but **if you are using XSD 1.1 you can define only once a complete *xs:unique* and then in the rest of the elements use *xs:unique ref="name"***. This is not valid for you as you are using XSD 1.0, but I let it here for future XSD 1.1 users that find this good question.

Example (namespaces removed for clarity):

```
<xs:element name="map">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" type="MapEntryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- Only completely defined once -->
    <xs:unique name="uniqueEntry">
        <xs:selector xpath="entry"/>
        <xs:field xpath="key"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="hashMap">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" type="MapEntryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- Referenced here and every other time -->
    <xs:unique ref="uniqueEntry"/>
</xs:element>
```