# Unique element value in xml via xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, unique-constraint, xml-validation

I have a xsd which has to prevent duplicate values for an element. I tried various ways and was somehow missing to achieve unique constraint for an element.

In the below xml, i have **xyz:interval** element having duplicate values.
How to avoid the duplication using unique tag?

I have tried using unique in below XSD, but was not able to achieve the same.

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xyz="http://www.example.com/schema/public/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/schema/public/" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="Intervals">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="interval" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:unique name="alias_unique">
                <xs:selector xpath="supportedMeasurementIntervals" />
                <xs:field xpath="." />
            </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="defaultInterval" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="NoOfPeriod" type="xs:int" />
<xs:element name="isPeriodSupported" type="xs:boolean" />
<xs:element name="MType">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="SIntervals" type="xyz:Intervals" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:group name="Child">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SIntervals" type="xyz:Intervals" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element ref="xyz:NoOfPeriod" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element ref="xyz:isPeriodSupported" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<xs:element name="Parent">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:group ref="xyz:Child" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MTypes" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element ref="xyz:MType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xyz:Parent xmlns:xyz="http://www.example.com/schema/public/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema/public/">
    <xyz:Child>
        <xyz:SIntervals>
            <xyz:interval>1111</xyz:interval>
            <xyz:interval>1111</xyz:interval>
            <xyz:interval>1111</xyz:interval>
            <xyz:interval>9727</xyz:interval>
            <xyz:defaultInterval>504</xyz:defaultInterval>
        </xyz:SIntervals>
        <xyz:NoOfPeriod>4804</xyz:NoOfPeriod>
        <xyz:isPeriodSupported>1</xyz:isPeriodSupported>
    </xyz:Child>
    <xyz:MTypes>
        <xyz:MType id="string" />
        <xyz:MType id="string" />
        <xyz:MType id="string">
            <xyz:SIntervals>
                <xyz:interval>2222</xyz:interval>
                <xyz:interval>2222</xyz:interval>
                <xyz:defaultInterval>6631</xyz:defaultInterval>
            </xyz:SIntervals>
        </xyz:MType>
        <xyz:MType id="string" />
    </xyz:MTypes>
</xyz:Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could change the maxOccurs="1" instead of "unbounded" in your definition of `Intervals`.

```
    [.....]
    <xs:complexType name="Intervals">
        <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="interval" type="xs:int" maxOccurs="1">
    [.....]
```

---

EDIT (After the comment)

1. you have to put your defined the namespace in the xpath expression.
2. as said in the comment, the `unique` apply to the scope of the `element`. you defined it a level too low.

for example, you could define the uniqueness in the scope of the `Child` element like following:

```
<xs:group name="Child">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="SIntervals" type="xyz:Intervals" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
        <xs:unique name="uniqueInterval">
            <xs:selector xpath="xyz:interval" />
            <xs:field xpath="." />
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element ref="xyz:NoOfPeriod" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:element ref="xyz:isPeriodSupported" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
</xs:sequence>
```

You'll then have to do it the same way for your other elements (or you re-design the definition).

Comment: I can have multiple interval definitions but not the values for them being the same. The xsd should fail the validation if values are repeated.

Comment: OK, I didn't get the question correctly. the unique apply to  scope of the element, but here, you want to apply it to a complexType, what is not possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826828/unique-constraint-on-a-complextype-instead-of-an-element. Maybe you'll have to redesign your xsd and definition of types.